# Trouble inserting data into SQLite table while skipping unique ID column (which is the primary key) in python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-insert

So I have a created table as shown below (just with more columns that are too long to paste in here):

```
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Income (       
            SS_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            age INTEGER,
            class_of_worker TEXT,
            detailed_industry_code TEXT,
            eductation TEXT,
```

The issue I am having is inserting the data from a large database (about 200,000 recrods) that is in the format as shown below (but with many more columns):

```
73, Not in universe, 0, 0, High school graduate, 0, Not in universe, Widowed,
#with 73 corresponding to age and so on
```

I am currently trying to import the data with the following:

```
with open('census-income.data', 'r') as data:
no_records = 0 
for row in data:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Income VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
                row.split(","))
    census_income.commit()
    no_records += 1 
    census_income.close() 
    print('\n{} Records Transfered'.format(no_records))
```

However this does not work as it tries import age (the first column in the data) into SS_ID (the first column in the table which is the primary key and has autoincrement for IDing records) and I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: IntegrityError
UNIQUE constraint failed: Income.SS_ID
```

Is there a way to import the data either by just importing specific columns of data into specific columns of the table, or by skipping the first column (SS_ID PRIMARY KEY) when importing all the data?

Many thanks for any help, I have been struggling with this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You must enumerate the columns that will receive the values, something like:

```
INSERT INTO Income (age, class_of_worker, detailed_industry_code, eductation, ....) VALUES(?,?,....)
```

Comment: when I try this I get a "Incorrect number of bindings supplied" error despite the column names and number of "?" matching up?

Comment: @wp9r80 the error means that the values passed by row.split(",") are not as many as the ?